# How to send Gps Neo-6m data with Gsm Sim7000c communication on Arduino Uno to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, gps, arduino-uno, gsm

I want to send data to the mysql database from a website that I have hosted using the GSM SIM7000C module on Arduino Uno. However I get the results are just dots. Like this :

This is my code : [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kesk5k8MX4LDcX3udNowS1ZmhdhrUJ-i/view?usp=sharing]

Anybody can help me? I really need to finish this, I've tried it many times the result is still the same. However, when I run GPS and GSM separately they can, but when combined they cannot.

Comment: what do you mean by "GPS and GSM separately they can, but when combined they cannot"? do you mean they are on the same serial bus and hence they conflict with each other, or something else?  please include the relevant details in your question